# premature end of file in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

**Premature end of file Error in all xml files in Eclipse (android)**

I am having an error in my all xml files including manifiest file. It is "Premature end of file ". Now my all the xml files are blank ... I dont what happened to these file. 
Please anyone who know why this problem is occurring then please help me. I ll be very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Highlight your project name in project inspector and hit F5 to refresh. Go to Project menu and do "Clean..." and try to rebuild/open. If problem still occurs, browse to the folder your project files are in using any other application (Total Commander, Dopus etc) and inspect files yourself. Open XML files in text editor and check if they look corrupted. If they are - try to find out why this happened. Maybe your HDD is dying?

Comment: I refreshed and cleaned the project but problem is still occurring. And also i opened the xml files in notepad++ but nothing appeared on editor. The size of every file is 0KB now.

Comment: Then your file is gone. Restore from backup. If you do not have any, then sorry but you need to start from scratch. But in that case I'd first try to find out why this happened (if one file is gone then maybe you did something wrong cleared, saved accidentaly etc). If all are gone - then it's odd

Comment: All the files are gone. Earlier some days i sent this my script to someone via mail. I also downloaded the project from my sent items. It is also giving me same problem.

Comment: Well, if you unpack what you sent and still got 0 bytes, then maybe problem occured before you sent them and your sendout was also corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error **Premature end of the file** in my project after creating the spring-servlet.xml file in Eclipse IDE. Found no error syntactically in this file then **just closing the project and reopening it resolves the error**. Sometimes, closing and reopening the project can resolve such issues as it refreshes the IDE's internal state. It's a good practice to try this step if you encounter any unexplained errors or inconsistencies in Eclipse IDE.